# How to prevent Malicious POST Requests in a PHP application?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, vue.js, post

I'm developing a website which works like an online game and has a score system. After doing certain activities, the user receives some virtual coins which are stored in a SQL database through a page called "levelup.php".

The issue is that the user could directly access "levelup.php" or even send a malicious post request by using the browser's console by typing something like this:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "levelup.php", true);
xhttp.send();
```

How to prevent this and make sure that the user has actually done the required activities to earn the score?

ps: it is meant to be a game, so adding something like reCAPTCHA is not a viable solution.

EDIT:

The "levelup.php" file follows as below

```php
// update level xp
$conn = new mysqli(SERVER, USER, PASS, DB);
$conn->query("update level set xp = xp + 15 where user_id = 1");
$conn->close();
```

The page adds 15 points to the user everytime it is accessed without making sure they have played the game.

And here is what I do in a javascript file after each game is finished:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "levelup.php", true);
xhttp.send();
```

My question is how to make sure the user has played the game and is not simply accessing levelup.php?

Comment: How do you trigger this page in your application? Ajax? PHP POST?

Comment: Basically, you can't tell the difference between a request made by your JS code in the browser or from the console. As far as the server is concerned, they are two identical requests that comes from the same source/client (the browser). When writing game logic, all that should happen on the backend, with the client just sending events of what happens. Then you need to validate and sanity check those events in the backend before they are used.

Comment: points and level progression should be done serverside (db triggers or such), the client should only need access the state/scores/level, not change it

Comment: never ever trust the data you receive from the client-side(js and such). When the request is made to the levelup.php file, perform some checks like initial score, etc. I hope your app design logic already enforces strict checks

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton i'm using Ajax to call the levelup.php page. So every time this page is called, the level of the users goes up by one. How to make sure the user has actually played anythig?

Comment: It's a little hard to say without details, but in general you'd send the *evidence* to the server, and let the *server* decide if a level has been earned. In a quiz app, for example, you'd POST the user's answers, and on the server-side you'd decide if they were correct.

Answer (score -2):

implement a crf token or a random generated code with user credentials and embed it to the page

Comment: How would that stop them from passing that CSRF token from the console as well? CSRF tokens are for protecting endpoints from cross-site requests, while a call from the console (while having the page loaded) isn't cross-site.

Comment: random add nothing either, whilst a hmac at least signs what the client has so it cant be tampered with.